# Why doesn't the program print anything

Tags: python-3.x

***Here is my code***

```
import re
    email=input("Enter your email")
    def is_email(email):
        pattern = '[\.\w]{1,}[@]\w+[.]\w+'
        if re.match(pattern, email):
            return True
            print("Valid Email")    
        else:
            return False
            print("Invalid Email")
```

I am probably missing something very simple but would just like to know what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the function but never call it and return before your print statements.

```
import re

    def is_email(email):
        pattern = '[\.\w]{1,}[@]\w+[.]\w+'
        if re.match(pattern, email):
            print("Valid Email")    
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid Email")
            return False

    email=input("Enter your email")
    is_email(email)
```

Comment: You  have put the is_email(email) bit before it has been defined so the code wont run

Comment: @Lenard Indeed I did.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems (beside formatting):

1) You've defined a function, which is not called anywhere.

2) You return from the function, before you print. The code after the `return` statement never gets executed.